# Pound sign (£) getting wrongly identified by Azure RecognizeText API in Cognitive Services

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have many cases of pictures of texts where one can find a pound sign (£) but the sign is NEVER correctly recognized by Azure Cognitive Services RecognizeText API, as far as I tested. Other symbols, like the dollar sign ($) for example, are identified without problems.

I made tests with print screens of texts containing £, since these should be easy for the OCR tool to convert, and again the pound sign is not correctly identified (it becomes an f, a 2, a 1, a $ etc).

I am suspecting that the pound sign is not included in the set of characters that the tool supports, although I couldn't find a specific mention of that in the documentation (only that the tool is experimental and is optimized for English).

Has anyone been able to correctly convert a £ using the tool, or does anyone know FOR SURE (possibly through documentation)
 that £ is not included in their character set?

Thanks!